# javascript if && OR

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks,
  I have an if statement that should check if `err` is defined, and if so, see if its `ETIMEDOUT` or `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`

Is this syntactically sound?

```
if (err && err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT') {
}
```

Or Should it look like:

```
if (err && (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')) {
}
```

Comment: `(err && (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'))`

Comment: `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'` is a problem, because `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'` evaluates to either `true` or `false`, but `'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'` doesn't.

Comment: Before posting to StackOverflow, please try to run your program locally, or even post the results as a JSFiddle. If you find there is an error, then by all means, continue to ask. But testing out logic is simple to do yourself, even by printing `console.log()` statements.

Comment: The correct form is `x == y || z == z`. As it is written it is equivalent to `x == (y || z)`, which does not make sense. (And yes, there are *many* duplicates about this same syntax mistake..)

Comment: Your first code is syntactically sound, but not logically sound.  It would be the logical equivalent of just `if (err) { }` because `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'` will always evaluate to a truthy value.

Comment: @user2864740 I do not think it is a direct duplicate, but rather a simpler version of it. I agree though that it should be closed. I just do not know which option to choose.

Comment: @onebree Similar in spirit of the problem (the `&&` bit is superficial, and it's only a 2-or form) - there are probably better ones, but are somewhat hard to find.

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for marking this as duplicate! I wish there were an option for "needs more personal research", because this one does not even show error messages, so how would OP know whether he is right?

Answer (score 4):

It should be like that:

```
if (err && (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' || err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')) {
}
```

The reason is that in JavaScript:

> logical expressions are evaluated left to right

And && operator would create a 'connection' between `err` and `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'`, while OR would receive:

`(err && err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') || err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'`

Another problem was missing `err.code ===` in third expression and, as not empty string in JavaScript are truthy, it was always `true`.

Comment: Wow, stackoverflow. Just wow.

Comment: I think it may be one person downvoting multiple responses, as one of the other answers also got downvoted quickly.

Comment: Well, to be fair, the downvotes came in before you edited your answer.  Your original answer was just to add parentheses, which would not change the outcome in any way.

Comment: I did not vote any answer down, only the question for reasons I posted as a comment. One reason why you were voted down would be to promote another, similar answer. I saw that this answer was downvoted within 20 seconds of posting. ONLY suggestion I have is to provide more reasoning in this answer. Like, yes you copied one of 2 options asked by OP, but explain why your answer/option leads to the right logical outcome.

Comment: ... Seeing that your answer was (a) answered first, and (b) includes a closing curly brace, I will do you the favor to vote you up.

Comment: Very nice people here. ; )

Answer (score 3):

No, you must specify a full expression for each check against a variable.

```
if (err && (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' ||  err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')) {
```

The first check, just `err`, evaluates to a boolean, but just checking `'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'` would always evaluate to true.